# Scroll to top not working in responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div  that triggers this script to scroll to top. It stops working when the width of the window is smaller than 991px.

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
      $('.scrolltop:hidden').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  } else {
      $('.scrolltop').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }
});
$(function(){$(".scroll").click(function(){$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$("nav").offset().top},"1000");return false})})
</script>
```

Any idea? 
I'm adding the css of the media query.

```
/* ==== MEDIA QUERIES ==== */
@media screen and (max-width : 991px) {

body,html{
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.bloque-alto{
    min-height: 720px;
    padding: 70px 0 70px;
}    

#contacto{
    padding: 50px 0 70px;
}

#contacto2{
    background-image:none;
    background: #000;       
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 800px;
    padding: 80px 0 100px 0;
    min-height: 1000px;
}

#contacto2>.container>.row>.col-md-8>.row>.col-md-4{
    padding:20px 0 20px;
}

input.form-control.input-lg,textarea.form-control.input-lg{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Is the CSS for `nav` affected by any media device width queries?

Comment: give us a [mcve] that reproduces the current behavior

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have a media query with that exact width breakpoint (991px) but i cant figure out which property is generating the problem.